# Getting result value from dataframe after agg

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing simple Sum operation on values coming form text file with below code. I want to get result in the java code from dataframe.

How could I do it?

```
 SparkSession sc = jobContext.sparkSession();

    Dataset<Row> df = sc.read().format("csv")
    .option("header", "false") //Since text file doesnt contain any header
    .load("s3://test/input.txt") //configuring s3 bucket with txt file having numbers on each line
    .toDF("val"); //assigning column name values

    return "Sum is : " + df.select(sum("val"));
```

Gives me `Sum is : [Sum(val): double]` How do I get result from dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the first row and get it's field

```
 return "Sum is : " + df.select(sum("val").alias("sum")).first().getAs(0);
```

Comment: It is saying item doesnot exists :(